# PHP session cookie lifetime stuck on 0

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a login function that looks like this...

```
function sec_session_start() {
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
            session_start();           
            session_regenerate_id();    
        }

        $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   
        $secure = SECURE;
        $httponly = false;
        if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
            echo 'unsafeSession';
            exit();
        }
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        //session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
        session_set_cookie_params(315360000, $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
        session_name($session_name);
}
```

Where the session_set_cookie_params function contains 315360000 (10 years in seconds) as it's first argument and is supposed to define the cookie lifetime.

I recently change it to 315360000 from "$cookieParams["lifetime"]" (which you can see commented out above it), because users were being regularly logged out of the application and the following code simply returned 0...

```
$cookie_params = session_get_cookie_params();
echo $cookie_params['lifetime'];
```

What's confusing is that I thought 0 meant any time the application/browser closes you should be logged out - but that was NOT happening.  And now that I've replaced with 315360000 I'm seeing pretty much the exact same behaviour where sessions are ending after some period of inactivity (and the test code above is still returning 0).

Am I missing other considerations that could be causing this behaviour?  E.g. peculiarities with my machine/browser (even though I have no similar problem with other sites)?  Or should this be easily definable in code?  In which case perhaps I'm missing something there!  Thanks for any help.

Comment: why not just use $_SESSION and use the array? Cookies are fairly insecure...

Comment: I am using $_SESSION in places, but not sure exactly what you're suggesting in terms of changing my code - also, I thought that using session_set_cookie_params with "SECURE" as the penultimate parameter would prevent any security issues (e.g. javascript being able to access the session_id)

Comment: I use $_SESSION for logins like `$_SESSION['user']` - then you set session lifetime in php.ini - thus reduced code and not sure - too scared to touch anything to do with cookies

Comment: Ok got it thanks - and then I could simply do something like this right? ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 315360000);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 315360000);

Comment: yeah you can use ini_set - or if you know you're always going to manage the site server then you can set it in your .ini file :)

Comment: ok awesome, thanks!